# Recovering deleted items from a Nokia Lumia 920 running Windows Phone 8

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

Is it possible to recover deleted items from a Nokia Lumia 920 running Windows Phone 8? The files were stored in the phone's memory, not on an SD Card.

When I connect the phone to the computer I am able to browse files, but not through a drive letter which seems to be what most recovery programs need in order to do an "undelete".

Thanks!

Comment: What specifically was deleted? More details will help someone try to answer your question.

Comment: @caschw Videos.  I was trading phones with my son and before I had a chance to copy the videos off, he erased them.  The pictures weren't a problem since they were configured to automatically upload to SkyDrive, but the couple of videos I had were not.  He didn't wipe the phone, he just deleted them individually.

Comment: Think you are out of luck. There is no "trash can" concept that I am aware.

Comment: Could they have been automatically uploaded to SkyDrive?

Comment: @Neil As I mentioned in a previous comment, photos were uploaded, videos were not.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 8 removed the ability to connect to the computer using the USB mass storage protocol in favor of the MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). This means that while you can open your Windows Phone as a USB device on the computer, it does not appear as a drive; and data recovery software cannot access it.

Comment: Direct access to WP7 or WP8 file systems was never possible officially.

Comment: @NeilTurner That's true but you were able edit the registry keys to allow connection using mass storage